# Get glyph widths by fontforge script

Tags: fonts, truetype, fontforge

For getting glyph widths, I convert a `TTF` font to `AFM`, and then parse the content of `AFM` file to get the width of each glyph.

Since technically, `fontforge` is capturing the glyph widths from the binary `TTF` file, and then create a `AFM` font file based on the `AFM` standard template. I wonder if it is possible to directly convert a `TTF` file to a list of glyph widths by a fontforge command?!?

Comment: You'll probably get more help on this question if you tag it with the programming language you're using.

Comment: @CarlAnderson I don't want to use a programming language, I want to use `fontforge` to convert a `ttf` file to glyph widths.

Comment: To be honest I think this question belongs on either tex.stackexchange or superusers, since it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @CarlAnderson I do agree with you but not that neither `tex` or `superusers` are using `fontforge` as a programming tool to capture the glyph properties. The advanced users of `fontforge` are just programmers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FontForge includes two interpreters so you can write scripts to modify fonts. One of these interpreters is Python (preferred), one is a legacy language. Fontforge embeds Python but it is also possible to build Fontforge as a Python extension.

So what will you use: *Python* or *Legacy language*?
What interface: *Command line* or *GUI* or *Python extension*?

### Command line and Legacy Language

The script can be in a file, or just a string presented as an argument. You may need to specify which interpreter to use with the -lang argument. See [Command Line Arguments](http://fontforge.org/cliargs.html).

```
$ fontforge -script scriptfile.pe {arguments}
$ fontforge -c "script-string" {arguments}
$ fontforge -lang={ff|py} -c "script-string"
```

After scanning the [documentation](http://fontforge.org/scripting-alpha.html#GlyphInfo) I  wrote my scriptfile.pe:

```
Open($1, 1)
Select($2)
Print( GlyphInfo('Width') )
```

Than:

```
$ fontforge -script scriptfile.pe YourFont.ttf A
... # Some output truncated.
1298
```

### Execute Scripts from  GUI

Open a font. Than choose: 'File' > 'Execute script...'. Enter:

```
Select('A')
Error(ToString(GlyphInfo('Width')))
```

Click 'OK'.

[image: Fontforge Error Window]

### Python Extension

First the width of a single glyph ([docs](http://fontforge.org/python.html)):

```
>>> import fontforge
>>> f = fontforge.open("YourFont.ttf")
>>> f['A'].width
1298
```

Here the answer to your question. For each glyph the encoding index, name and width:

```
>>> for i in f.selection.all():
...    try:
...       name, width = f[i].glyphname, f[i].width
...       print i, name, width
...    except:
...       pass
... 
0 uni0009 0
2 uni0002 0
13 nonmarkingreturn 510
# ... Truncated ...
65707 germandbls.smcp 2266
>>>
```

Note: I used try/except because somehow `f.selection.all()` does also select non-glyphs. Accessing a glyph that doesn't exist will raise an error.