# How to get a glyph width from a ttf font using bash?

Tags: bash, glyph

[image: width of a glyph]

How to extract this number 1139 from the font file using bash?

otfinfo can show a list of glyphs.

```
otfinfo --glyphs *.ttf
```

I want to get info about each glyph something like this page:

http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/

But with bash.

I found that fontforge can do it,

[Get glyph widths by fontforge script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955954)

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? Please [edit] your question to include samble output from the `otfinfo` tool and your code so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Basically, you need to tell ImageMagick, from the command line, to create an image containing the word "Test" and ask it to tell you the font metrics in its debug output as it does so:

So, here is an example from Anthony Thyssen's excellent *"ImageMagick Usage Pages"* [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#font_info)

```
convert -debug annotate  xc: -font "/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf" -annotate 0 "Test" null: 
2018-07-10T09:36:53+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.7 Annotate convert[7893]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1545/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 12
2018-07-10T09:36:53+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.7 Annotate convert[7893]: annotate.c/GetTypeMetrics/931/Annotate
  Metrics: text: Test; width: 28; height: 15; ascent: 13; descent: -3; max advance: 21; bounds: 0.6875,-0.046875  5.96875,9; origin: 28,0; pixels per em: 12,12; underline position: -3.8125; underline thickness: 3.29688
2018-07-10T09:36:53+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 7.0.7 Annotate convert[7893]: annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1545/Annotate
  Font /Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 12
```

Hopefully you can see all the values of the various parameters detailed on Anthony's diagram:

[image]